# Custom template not showing in Easy Template Path Hints

Tags: magento-1.9, template

I am having an issue with my custom template showing up in Easy Template Path Hints. This was working fine until one day I noticed my Google Ads was not showing. I first checked to see if the Google links was still in place and the are. I then turned on Easy Template Path Hints and noticed my custom template is not showing. I have Magento 1.9.1 installed.

Below is a copy of my file structure.

[image: custom template in RWD folder]

[image: custom template in skins folder]

Comment: The folder you point to there is your theme. Is your entire theme no longer being used? Or are you just missing a single block?

Comment: @Tyler V. Thanks for your quick response. My entire theme is no longer being used.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings in `System > Configuration > Design`. It looks like you need **Current Package Name** set to `rwd` and **Default** set to `fsg_custom`.

You should also check these settings on a per-store level using the **Current Configuration Scope** dropdown at the top left of the page.

If those settings check out, try going to `System > Cache Management` and clicking **Flush Magento Cache**.

Comment: I have checked all of these settings and everything checks out but theme is still not being used

Comment: I made the assumption that this was working in the past and broke. But looking at your screenshots again, it looks like you don't have an etc folder and  therefore no theme.xml file in your theme. Which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: Yes this was working in the past. I have an etc folder but I dont have a theme.xml file. I am using 1.9.1

Comment: Can you follow this article to setup your theme, and then check back here? http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes

Comment: I tried the setup from the link above but it did not work. After I added the theme.xml file to the etc folder the website remained broken, there is no css. I also noticed that before trying the setup in the link above, I moved my original theme (fsg_custom) up one level out of the rwd folder and my google ads came back  but my sub categories in the nav does not exist and of course no responsiveness. There is also no left side bar. I wanted to upload screen shots of everything but I guess you cant use rich content when commenting.